# Does Java synchronized block work same with "this" and with a method parameter?

Tags: java, thread-synchronization, synchronized-block

How Java synchronization behaves if a method parameter is used in the synchronization block instead of **this** keyword.

```
public void doSomething(final MyInterface iface) {
  synchronized(this) {
    // ... do some work
  }
}
```

vs

```
public void doSomething(final MyInterface iface) {
  synchronized(iface) {
    // ... do some work
  }
}
```

Will the net effect be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two cases are *completely* different.

When you use `synchronized`,  a lock (monitor) is obtained on the object that is passed as argument.

`synchronized(this)` --> Thread obtains lock on "current" object.

`synchronized(iface)` --> Thread obtains lock on "iface" object

> Will the net effect be the same?

No, the effects could be devastatingly different.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever read `JLS`? Synchronization on `this` keyword implies synchronization on object itself (on which method was invoked). It is clear that `this` object and object referenced by parameter aren't same things in general.